# Can I pre-select a value in a <select> populated by AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following code:

```
<select
   data-ng-disabled="modal.action=='delete'"
   data-ng-model="modal.formData.contentTypeId"
   data-ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in option.contentTypes">
</select>
```

The code populates a select box with different contentTypes. However when the select box appears then initially nothing is selected and it is blank.

Is there a way I could have it select the first of the contentTypes as a default ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set default value in your controller

> $scope.modal.formData.contentTypeId= option.contentTypes[0].id